# HTML name attributes not changing using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a system which allows users to add different ticket types. I want each ticket property to have a unique name so that when the form is submitted I can tell the tickets apart.

Right now, there is a button to add more tickets to the page if the user needs more than one.

I have tried to get it to append the ticket number to the html name attribute but it's not working. It is successfully creating more ticket divs but its using the same name attribute.

Can anyone help with this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="tickets">
  <div id="ticket" class="form-inline  margin-bottom-40">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3">
         Ticket 
        <span class="required"> * </span>
     </label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="ticketname" /> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" name="ticketprice" />
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Quantity" name="ticketmax" /> 
        <a onclick="moreTickets()">
           <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
   <br>
   <br> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

**More tickets javascript**

```
var counter = 0;

function moreTickets() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('ticket').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('tickets');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace following code

**from**

```
var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
     var theName = newField[i].name
     if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
```

**to**

```
var newField = newFields.querySelectorAll("input");
for(var i=0; i<newField.length; i++){
    var theName = newField[i].name;
    if(theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
```

Check this link at w3schools for [details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).

Note that above implementation doesn't clear the values in the newly added section. You will have to manually clear it off.

**Updated with browser screenshot**
[image: name updated]

Comment: Thanks. The name attributes are still remaining the same but i'll have a look at w3schools and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @FMC I have added the screenshot displaying the effect of change. Please refresh your browser and see if script is updated properly.

Comment: This works just fine, I have checked this. Use inspect element, you can see the name attributes are incremented by 1 each time. `ticketname` => `ticketname1` / `ticketprice` => `ticketprice1` / `ticketmax` => `ticketmax1`

Comment: Ah yes you're right sorry. I just looked at the bottom element and seen it was the same, I didn't realise the bottom element is actually the first one. Thanks @CuriousMind!

Comment: You can use :  newField[i].setAttribute('name',theName + counter); to set the new name to each element

Answer (score 0):

Thought i would add a jquery alternative for reference

```js
$(function() {

  var tktGrp = $('#ticket').clone(), // deep clone of code block
      lstGrp = '#ticket .col-md-8',
    numCount = 1;

  $('#addTickets').click(function() {

      numCount++; // Increment 
    
      $(lstGrp + ':last').after(tktGrp.html()); // Get last group in the list and add the new html based on the clone

      $(lstGrp + ':last .dub').each(function() { // loop and change namp property of all dub classes

         $(this).prop('name', $(this).prop('name') + "-" + numCount);

       });
  });
  
  // UX: never display the first remove button : Still add to html so that we dont have to write html in the js
  $(lstGrp +':first button').remove(); 
  
  $(document).on( 'click', '[name*="remove"]', function(){ // Delegate for newly created objects
    $(this).parent().empty();
    numCount--; // Decrement
    
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="tickets">
  <div id="ticket" class="form-inline  margin-bottom-40">
    <div class="col-md-8 ticket-group-1">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 control-label">
        Ticket
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control dub" placeholder="Name" name="ticketname" />
      <input type="text" class="form-control dub" placeholder="Price" name="ticketprice" />
      <input type="text" class="form-control dub" placeholder="Max Quantity" name="ticketmax" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dub" name="remove">Remove</button>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="addTickets" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </div>


</div>
```